# How do i combine 3 tables in one query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys how do i combine this 3 tables in one single query in php?

PHP

```
<?php  
         $db_name = "atfest_db";  
         $mysql_user = "root";  
         $mysql_pass = "";  
         $server_name = "localhost";  
         $sql =  "SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name FROM sport as A right join matches 
       as B right join schedule as C ON A.s_id = B.s_id ORDER by m_id asc";
         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 
         $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

        {
        array_push($response, array("teamone"=>$row[0], "teamtwo"=>$row[1], 
        "s_name"=>$row[2]));

        }

        echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response));




        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Sport table is connected to matches b s_id while matches table is connected to schedule table by m_id

**Matches Table**
[image]

**Schedule Table**
[image]

**Sport Table**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can join two or more table using join() in mysql like:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2 
FROM table1 as t1 JOIN table2 as t2
on t1.some_col = t2.some_col    // where t1, t2 have a common column on which joining is done
where condition;
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL-statement instead:

```
SELECT B.teamone,B.teamtwo,A.s_name  
FROM sport A  
LEFT JOIN matches B  
LEFT JOIN schedule C  
ON A.s_id = B.s_id  
ORDER by C.m_id asc
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. this one sir

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `schedule`.`id`, (and other relevant fields from schedule table), `matches`.`m_id`, `matches`.`teamone`, `matches`.`teamtwo`, (and other relevant fields from matches table), `sport`.`s_id`, (and other relevant fields from sport table)
FROM `sport`
RIGHT JOIN `matches` ON `matches`.`s_id` = `sport`.`s_id`
RIGHT JOIN `schedule` ON `schedule`.`m_id` = `matches`.`m_id`
ORDER BY `schedule`.`id`
```

The above query will solve your basic question of combining three tables. But this is a bad practice. There will be a lot of redundant data. You're selecting only three column. In that, there is no index also. You can't figure out how each row is different from one another. Please mention the purpose or the logic of the query. So that we can fine tune the query accordingly.

### Update

I've updated the columns which we are selecting in the query. Now there is a unique column schedule id to uniquely identify each row. You can select other columns also depends upon the necessity.

Comment: This is for scheduling purposes sir. Where in the scheduled date and venue are stored in the schedules table, the teams participating in the matches and the sports name in the sports name. I am trying to echo this in one json object.

Comment: gives me and error like this sir, mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @orange: please put the below code after mysqli_query() function. `if($result){ print_r($result); die();}else{ var_dump(mysqli_error($con)); die();}` Please post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name FROM sport A 
LEFT JOIN matches B ON A.m_id=B.m_id
LEFT JOIN schedule C ON A.s_id = B.s_id ORDER by A.m_id asc

Comment: gives me and error like this sir, mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the right query for you . You are getting error because you are not using right query..

SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name FROM sport as A right join matches as B ON A.s_id = B.s_id right join schedule as C ON B.m_id = C.m_id order by B.m_id asc

Now you can go through it to get the appropriate result .This query is generated according to your schema.